# Mavericks not keeping "Arrange by" when view NAS items

Tags: finder, nas

I am set my finder to always show in Column view and with "Arrange By" set to Kind and "Sort By" set to name.

The problem is, when I open up my Synology NAS folder, the "Arrange By" has reverted back to None.

Comment: Although this sounds trivial, it has a huge performance impact when browsing shares on a large array. In my case, instead of showing the root folders, it's also showing the next level of folders. Very slow, and I have to hurry to change Arrange By to Name.